# Classificar resultados com uma condicional e agrupar numa coluna no R

Tags: r, formatação-condicional

tenho uma coluna com a variavel idade

```
age =c( 57, 17, 10, 21, 18, 21, 21, 23, 57, 13, 21, 14,  9, 40, 23, 25, 25, 44, 29, 28, 53, 55, 48, 12, 43, 13)
```

e gostaria de criar uma nova coluna classificando a idade em categorias <12 anos coloque 1, <=12 e>=30 coloque 2 e assim por diante ,

Comment: Está difícil de entender a pergunta pois os classificadores em R são usados ​​para delinear informações em conjuntos de dados de modelos preditivos, outra coisa que me chama atenção é fato de você querer adicionar uma nova coluna em um vetor, não faz muito sentido nova coluna em um vetor. Eu estou a mais de 45 min tentando entender sua pergunta e minha interpretação é a seguinte, você gostaria de aplicar uma função predicado a cada elemento de um vetor e colocar o resultado num data frame? Algo parecido com isso https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/SillyFirstShell#main.r

Comment: Olá, agradeço muito sua ajuda, era exatamente o que eu precisava, editei a pergunta ver se tornei ela mais clara.

Comment: A principal dificuldade que eu estou a ver é saber quais são os limites das categorias, *"e assim por diante"* não é lá muito util.

Comment: No exemplo 0-12;13-30;30;ou mais ... Indexado 1,2,3. ...

Comment: Tente `cut(age, breaks = c(0, 12, 30, Inf)) |> as.integer()`.

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode usar o comando `mutate()` para criar uma nova coluna `new_age`, por exemplo, juntamente com o comando `case_when()` para criar as condicionais dentro do `mutate()`.

As suas regras nao ficaram claras eu partir do principio que você gostaria:

age<12 = 1

age >=12 e age <30 = 2

age >=30 = 3

````
```{r}
library(dplyr)
```

```{r}

#vetor
age=c( 57, 17, 10, 21, 18, 21, 21, 23, 57, 13, 21, 14,  9, 40, 23, 25, 25, 44, 29, 28, 53, 55, 48, 12, 43, 13)

#converte esse vetor para um data.frame
df<-data.frame(age)%>%
  #usa a função mutate para criar uma nova coluna new_age
  #usa a função case_when para determinar as condicionais
  mutate(new_age=case_when(
    age<12~1,
    age >=12 & age <=30 ~2,
    TRUE~3))
df
```
````

age new_age

57  0
17  2
10  1
21  2
18  2
21  2
21  2
23  2
57  0
13  2

Answer (score -3):

```
rm(list = ls())
library(dplyr)


df <- data.frame( age= c(57, 17, 10, 21, 18, 21, 21, 23, 57, 13, 21, 14,9, 40, 23, 25, 25, 44, 29, 28, 53, 55, 48, 12, 43, 13))|>
  arrange(age)|>
  mutate(faixa= if_else(age<=30, 1, 2))
```

Dividi entre menores e maiores de 30, pode ser adicionada outras idades seguindo o modelo.